# Anchor Tags Breaking Page That Has Hashchange URL

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor, hashchange

I am using hashchange to navigate a site with content being shown/hidden.  Problem is, I also want to have a page jump using an anchor tag. This breaks the site and displays the initial content.  I can't seem to find a workaround for this.

Is there a way to build a function that brings you to an anchor tag without using `<a href="#anchor">Link to Anchor</a>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scrolling patch:

```
$(".scroll-link").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  $("body,html").animate({scrollTop: $(url).scrollTop()});
})
```

And just add the `.scroll-link` to the links that you want to scroll instead of using the hashchange. Plus it animates the scrolling.

Comment: This is awesome, and I will probably use it at some point for something else, but I should have explained in better detail.   The site is technically one page, but with divs being hidden/shown.  The links on the initial page state are 4 links of recent articles within a section that is hidden. So when the link to Article 1 is clicked, I want the hidden section to be displayed at the point where Article 1 lives.   I ended up creating another hashchange state and using `scrollIntoView();` to jump to the article. I actually don't want it to animate in this case.

Comment: Actually, if you were going to use this, you would have to add `e.preventDefault()` to stop the link from going through.